# Importing components from react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to understand how to work with `react-bootstrap`.
I have imported the whole `js` file like this in my `index.html`:

```
<!-- react-bootstrap -->
<script src="lib/react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In another `js` file I am creating a `Navbar`, and I found out that I have to create a variable from the `ReactBootstrap` like this:

```
var Navbar = ReactBootstrap.Navbar;
...
const MyNavBar = (
  <Navbar className="navbar-dark" fluid>
    ...
  </Navbar>
);
```

Do I need to do it for every component I want too use? If so, it seems like the normal `Bootstrap` css was much easier..

Answer (score 2):

React-Bootstrap has been optimized for use with tools like [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). When you grab the minified distribution we provide you are forced to download the entire library, even if you don't necessarily use all of it in your application. For a great run down on the benefits of those tools checkout [Pete Hunt - How Instagram Works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkTCL6Nqm6Y).

If that is an option you are not ready to explore you can re-assign the `ReactBootstrap` variable to something shorter like `var rb = ReactBootstrap;` requiring less typing.

I understand your concern about perceived simplicity of raw Bootstrap vs React-Bootstrap. Though when using React, React-Bootstrap's JavaScript implementation of the various Bootstrap components is done in an idiomatic React way, which is a lot easier than using the JavaScript Bootstrap provides.

Comment: OK I understand what you are saying, but even though if I want to use `react-bootstrap` component I need to require each one of them, am I right? I think it is easier just to write the class names as bootstrap, or am I missing something?

Comment: React-Bootstrap does more than apply css class names. It also does interactive Dropdowns, Modals, Accordians, etc. In a React idiomatic way, whereas the core Bootstrap team uses jQuery which doesn't play well with React.